# R Shiny + Future + Plumber

Tags: r, shiny, plumber, r-future

### Preamble

Inspired by the presentation by Barret Schloerke at studio::global(2021) (I will add the link as soon as it becomes available), I tried to implement an app to see the differences between using `{future`}, `{plumber}`, both or none into a Shiny app running a sequence of fast-slow-slow-fast computations (both on distinct output and in a sequence within the same one).

### Gist

You can find [here](https://gist.github.com/CorradoLanera/a3d39f35c5d8fa91297f0974e8b820af) my attempt, including the `app.R` Shiny app and the `plumber.R` APIs.

### Results

| execution selected (5 s for "slow") | result | expectation | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Standard run | ~20 seconds before anything appear, next everything appears in the same moment | ~20 seconds, appearing sequentially somehow | Why did not appear sequentially? |
| `{future}` only | ~5 seconds before anything appear, next everything appears in the same moment | ~20 with "first fast" and "second fast" appearing almost immediatly and next (~5) "first slow" or "second slow," next (~10) the other, and finally (~20) "Sequential") | I would expect that something similar to what happened here for the combined type of run... how is possible that "sequential" completed in 5 seconds??? |
| `{plumber}` only | same as the standard run (r should remain busy until each API call would be resolved, right?) | same time (~20) but appearing sequentially some how | why shiny rendered everything the same time? |
| `{future}` and `{plumber}` | same as the standard run | I do not expect this at all!, What I expected here is to have "*_fast"s appearing immediately, "*_slow"s quite the same time after ~5 seconds, and "sequential" after ~10 seconds from the start (i.e., ~10 seconds overall) | I am totally confused here :-( |

### Doubts

One of the main things I did not understand is why when activating `{future}` (both with or without `{plumber}`), "first fast" does not appear immediately. And in general, why the output does not appear in a single sequence when `{future}` is not involved. And how is it possible that with `{future}` alone, "sequential" stay ~5 seconds?

So, clearly, I made something the wrong way, and I do not understand something correctly.

### Questions

Can someone help me understand where/what (and maybe try to infer "why") I made the app wrong, and/or the API wrong, or their interaction wrong?

Thank you,
Corrado.

Comment: I have added an additional (second) version of app and API including `{future}` into the API. It does not change from the first version.

Comment: from first glance, I see that you did something a bit differently. in the presentation, the code inside the plumber expression was wrapped in a future. What you did is wrap the call to the plumber Api into a future, I do not think it is the same.

Comment: I think of that, and created the second version of both the files, but things doesn't change.

Comment: @Corrado could we use plumber and shiny together, if yes could you send me a link for the app or git repo and user documentation which really helps me alot